# jQuery mobile popup call from JS

Tags: jquery, mobile, popup

I have defined popup div and i want to open on some event, not using href. I have defined popup div like:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupDialog" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="c" style="max-width:400px;" class="ui-corner-all">        
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-top">
            <h1>Sample Page</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content">                
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">OK</a>    
        </div>
    </div>
```

and I tried calling this popup div

```
$("#popupDialog").popup;
$("#popupDialog").popup();
$("#popupDialog").popup("open");
```

None of them are not working. Any suggestion.

Comment: Would need to see the markup for what is supposed to call the popup, which is generally by an href , but should be possible using $.mobile.changePage, but without that markup/script i would be flapping in the breeze

Comment: I want to display pop message on some validation like form submission

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was doing this just the other day, and this is how it works for me. The code is on [jsFiddle so you can check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/jb8Jx/) and also here is the code for consistency issues. Also, you may want to make sure you're referencing the [newest 1.2 version](http://jquerymobile.com/download/).

This js code goes just before the `</head>` tag:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#popupLogin" ).popup( "open" );            
});​
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>    
    <section id="home" data-role="page">
        <header data-role="header">
            <h1>test page</h1>
        </header>

        <div data-role="popup" id="popupLogin" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all">
            <h3 class="centerText">Register free!</h3>
            <div class="popup">
                <form>                
                      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="centerText" placeholder="email" data-theme="a"/>
                      <button type="submit" data-theme="b">Sign me up</button>

                      <p class="centerText">
                          text1<br/>
                          text2<br/>
                          etc...<br/>
                      </p>                
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This Question was  [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559883/jquery-mobile-popup-is-not-opening-on-popupopen)

```
$(document).on({
    "pageinit": function () {
        alert("pageinit");
        //$("#popupBasic").popup('open'); will throw error here because the page is not ready yet
        //simulate ajax call here
        //data recieved from ajax - might be an array, anything
        var a = Math.random();
        //use this to transfer data betwene events
        $(this).data("fromAjax", a);
    },
    //open popup here
    "pageshow": function () {
        alert("pageshow");
        //using stored data in popup
        $("#popupBasic p").html("Random : " + $(this).data("fromAjax"));
        //open popup
        $("#popupBasic").popup('open');
    }
}, "#page1");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/MvwBU/